# Firebase cloud function not returning a value, return data is always null

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm rather new to firebase and have been trying to return a value after executing a cloud function. I can see the function is running smoothly. It just returns a null data. How

This is to get the result from the firebase cloud function. httpCallable

Unable to receive a value from Firebase cloud function. Here is my function code. The function is running smoothly. It is just that it returns  a null data.

```js
exports.checkDewBubble = functions.https.onCall( (data) => {
const ref = db.collection("users").doc(userID).collection("results").doc("dpbp")
...
some calculation
...

ref.update({

    enter code here
        bubblePoint: bubblePoint - 273.15,
        dewPoint: dewPoint - 273.15
    })
    .then(() => {

        return {
            dew: (bubblePoint - 273.15).toFixed(2),
            bubble: (bubblePoint - 273.15).toFixed(2)
        }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed to connect' + err.message)
})
```

Here the code  by which the app calling the function....

```js
let checkDewBubble = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('checkDewBubble')
    checkDewBubble(data)
    .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)

    this.dewPoint =  result.data.dew
    this.bubblePoint =  result.data.bubble

    const ref = db.collection("users").doc(userID).collection("results").doc("dpbp")

   ref.get().then((doc)=>{
                            console.log(doc.data().dewPoint, doc.data().bubblePoint)
        this.dewPoint =  doc.data().dewPoint
        this.bubblePoint =  doc.data().bubblePoint

        })
        .then(()=>{ 

             some code


        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error)
            this.$store.dispatch('setLoading',false)
            // this.status = false
        })`
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dew' of null"

I am expecting a value of the dewPoint.

Comment: Callable functions need to return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete.  Your function isn't actually returning a value to the client (there is no top-level return statement).  Returning a value from a `then` callback isn't the same as returning a promise at the top level.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for the reply. Are you suggesting that if I keep my return statement before I update the database, i.e., before the "ref.update" in my code, it is going to work?

Comment: I shall try your suggestion and let you know how it goes, soon. Thanks again

Comment: It worked! Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from Frank and Doug. 
I resolved the issue by returning a promise. Also, I realized that I have to return the promise just before the closure of the http callable cloud function and not inside any inner async methods..

I'm posting my corrected code for anyone who may face the same issue

```js
exports.checkDewBubble = functions.https.onCall( (data) => {

//some code including async functions

const ref = db.collection("users").doc(userID).collection("results").doc("dpbp")
        return ref.update({
                bubblePoint: parseFloat(bubblePoint),
                dewPoint: parseFloat(dewPoint)
            })
            .then(() => {   

                return {
                    dew: (dewPoint - 273.15).toFixed(2),
                    bubble: (bubblePoint - 273.15).toFixed(2)
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed to connect' + err.message)

            })
          
})
```

This returns the object to the client side and thus resolved.